# Recover data on OnePlus

Tags: data-recovery, oxygenos, oneplus

I'm trying to recover data from my phone cache or anywhere else my phone hides data from me. I have the new OnePlus 12 as well as my previous OnePlus 8t.

I'm not tech illiterate, and I'm not a tech genius. I'm looking for deleted data on both phones. I don't want to root the new OnePlus 12. I can root the OnePlus 8t, not that I know how to.

I'm seeking an intelligent, patient, individual who can ensure accurate phone guidance, in layman's terms.

Comment: Please note that Stackexchange is a question and answer site, not a forum. Thus it is a bit more impersonal as you may expect. This site is good if you have a concrete technical question, which technical details. Your question could be improved with more details because at the moment you only tell us that you have these two OnePlus phones and try to recover some data. But not on which device, what data, why the data is lost, how it happened, when it happened, what you have tried so far...

Comment: I'm closing this question as a duplicate to 'How to recover a deleted file from /data partition on a rooted phone?" because that's the usual case of recovering deleted data. While it might be very technical, it can't be helped, because recovering deleted data itself is not an easy task at all on Android. Otherwise, you might want to [edit] and clarify the issue as Robert has commented.

Answer (score 0):

What type of files are you attempting to recover?

For image and media files, your best and most viable bet is to attempt to recover from cache (don't get your hopes up, as these are likely downsampled thumbnails, etc.).  There are numerous applications that do exactly this, so a Google search will lead you to these apps (we don't give app recommendations).

If the data you are seeking to recover are within the domain of what gets synchronized by your Chrome browser or Google Account, then you *might* be able to get the data back.  You can check the internal page `chrome://sync-internals` and dump the data and decompress it to sift through.  You can also trigger a server-side sync event so that the contents update in the correct direction to recover you data.

Lastly, Google Backup can also be used to do the same, but it's a little trickier because there's no direct UI for you to manage the sync specifics.  I can't recall exactly, but I remember reading there was an ADB command to manually trigger sync, it might be worth taking a look into if it helps your situation.

Hope that helps, and good luck!